# How to solve the heap size issue in test classes

Tags: unit-test, heap

I created test class for Apex Class .test class code coverage 90% but I can't move from sandbox to production because an error is thrown regarding heaps size: `Heap Size 6798787`. What can I do to avoid this?

```
List<Account> acclist = [SELECT Description ,Fax, Id, Name,AccountNumber, Key_test__c,Phone, Rating, Site, Type,BillingPostalCode, 
                                 ShippingStreet,SAP_Account_Number__c,ShippingPostalCode,RecordType.Name, SystemModstamp, TickerSymbol,Website,AuthCode__c 
                                 FROM Account where RecordTypeId =:rectype order by CreatedDate desc ];
        System.debug('Acclist:'+acclist);  

        for(Account a:acclist){

            System.debug('SAP Account Number:'+a.SAP_Account_Number__c);
            if(a.SAP_Account_Number__c != null)
            {
                mapPracNum.put(a.SAP_Account_Number__c,a);

            }

            if(a.BillingPostalCode != null)
            {
                String s1 = a.Name+'_'+a.BillingPostalCode;
                if(!mapPracNamePostCode.containsKey(s1))
                {
                    mapPracNamePostCode.put(s1,a);  
                }
            }
        }
```

I query the account total account records 500. Now, I moved to this class from sand to production I got heap size issue.

Thanks
Kittu

Comment: Can you edit your question to share your code? There's not enough information here to help you as the question stands.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything as it is, I'm assuming there's more going on? 500 accounts in a map shouldn't be a problem, check that you don't have cascading triggers causing it to blow up.

Comment: What version is the testmethod running at? That is, in PROD, if running at pre V23.0, the testmethod will retrieve all Accounts in PROD for that recType.  Same thing will happen if you have @isTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation on the testmethod.